# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0, java 7

Tags: hibernate, maven, jboss, persistence, pom.xml

I have an web app, with spring,thymeleaf,hibernate and java 7. My pom have the following added dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

My persistence.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="unidadPersistencia" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>  
         <class>es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.entity.SolicitudTelematica</class>
         <class>es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.entity.ProcedimientoAsociado</class>
         <class>es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.entity.DocumentacionAdjunta</class>
         <class>es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.entity.BandejaSalida</class>
         <class>es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.entity.SolicitudCampamentos</class>
         <class>es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.entity.SolicitudCampamentosResultas</class>
         <class>es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.entity.SolicitudCampamentosUrgencia</class>
         <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/><!-- QUE DRIVER USA -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://10.199.247.82:1433;databaseName=AvanteDXXS_Pruebas"/> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="******"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*******"/>
         </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And when i run the jboss server i obtain the error `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` but if i change the hibernate.entitymanager version to a previous one, i obtain PersistenceProvider not found 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'

Comment: You're using a version of Hibernate compiled for Java 8 and trying to run it on Java 7.